# How to set maxY maxX for a default report?

Tags: jmeter

How can I set maxY for a graph in the jmeter dashboard report? For the LatencyOverTime graph I tried with the property line below with no result?

`jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.property.maxY=2000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

In your user.properties set:

`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.graph_options.latenciesOverTime.maxY=2000`